# IAudioEndpointVolume has no member named GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc

Consider this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  IAudioEndpointVolume *wh;
  IMMDevice *ya;
  IMMDeviceEnumerator *xr;
  CoInitialize(0);
  CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&xr);
  xr->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(eRender, eConsole, &ya);
  ya->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioEndpointVolume), CLSCTX_ALL, 0, (void**)&wh);
  float zu;
  wh->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(&zu);
  printf("%d\n", (int) round(100 * zu));
}
```

I can compile it as C++ with no issue:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ vol.cpp -lole32
```

However if I try to compile it as C:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc vol.c -lole32
```

I get errors such as:

```
error: ‘IAudioEndpointVolume’ has no member named ‘GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar’
```

This program does not seem to be particularly “C++”, so what is causing the
problem? Also, can I change something so that it compiles as C?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
  IAudioEndpointVolume *wh;
  IMMDevice *ya;
  IMMDeviceEnumerator *xr;
  CoInitialize(0);
  CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    &IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, (void**)&xr);
  xr->lpVtbl->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(xr, eRender, eConsole, &ya);
  ya->lpVtbl->Activate(ya, &IID_IAudioEndpointVolume, CLSCTX_ALL,
    0, (void**)&wh);
  float zu;
  wh->lpVtbl->GetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(wh, &zu);
  printf("%d\n", (int) round(100 * zu));
}
```

Changes:

1. `#include <initguid.h>`
2. `&CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator` instead of `__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator)`
3. `lpVtbl->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint` instead of `GetDefaultAudioEndpoint`

[Source](http://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/fonction-de-volume-windows-son#message-89033908)